# PHP - Generate images from at set coordinates

Tags: php, jquery, image, web-applications

Here's a scenario (with PHP and jQuery):

- Have a drag and drop interface, lets say a square in the center of the screen
- Generate an image from that area's coordinates

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You mean selecting cropping area with http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html and then doing the actual crop with imagemagick or php/GD?

Comment: Kinda... but instead of an image, it would be a div with image objects inside of it. Then an image would be generated after post processing.

Comment: It's possible width Php/GD, but a bit more complex than the usual JCrop solution.

Comment: No, thats not possible with usual javascript/php. You need something that does screenshot (has access to video memory), like java applet. Unless you store everything in javascript canvas (but there are no divs).. Try http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/